# Can I leverage the built-in Duration Field in a Events List

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Trying to add a view to a spo event list that get the total duration of the events in the list. I found a built-in Duration field accessible though PNP Powershell (e.g. $event.fieldValues.Duration) that seems to be reporting duration in seconds. I can add the field to a view using Add/Set-PNPView, but when I try adding `-aggregations "<FieldRef Name='Duration' Type='Sum'/>"` to the command, I get count=undefined on the list view.

I'm not used to using the -aggregations parameter so I'm not sure of the syntax and have found documentation to be fairly thin on that point.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually create the *Duration* column in Type of **Number** in the event list first.

Here is the sample command I test with:

```
Set-PnPView -List "Test calendar" -Identity "All Events" -Fields "ID","Title","Start Time","End Time","Duration" -Aggregations "<FieldRef Name='Duration' Type='Sum'/>"
```

And the outcome:
[image]

Comment: I tried that command line and I'm still getting "count=undefined." In your example, you're using the built-in Duration field, yes?

Comment: @steam23 Yes, custom column in the list and the built-in Duration field in the PowerShell.